# Json fetch queue

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My very first post here so I hope my request is going to be clear :-)

I have a php page that reads a JSON from a remote website.
This JSON contains a list of names, for each name I then need to read another JSON page containing the details of these ppl.

The whole things runs properly but it is damn slow. In the first page there are about 100 records, and in total the page takes about a minute and a half.

I don't really think there is a way to make it faster, I could cache the data, but the first time it runs it's still really slow.

I was thinking if I could, somehow, put the whole process in background and let the user continue doing his stuff while the data gets fetched.

Also, in case I have more users doing the same thing (different jsons pages ofc) i wanted to know if it was possible to create a queue of processes.

My websites runs on a linux server, I can't put my hands on the server, other than uploading files :(
The website is written in php + bootstrap and I have a mysql database.

Thank you in advance for any possible help :)

Comment: Are you sure this is code issue? What is the network time to access that remote website?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting JSON data back, I would remove the PHP middleman from the solution entirely, and get the data directly into the webpage using Ajax requests from Javascript. These can be made to execute asynchronously so it won't matter so much if it takes a bit of time.

This is assuming of course that you can safely authenticate to whatever service you're accessing, using Javascript (e.g. this might be a problem if you can't/won't expose credentials to the end-user).

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking if i could, somehow, put the whole process in background and let the user continue doing his stuff while the data gets fetched.

you cannot do that as you are working with a webserver, you cannot send data without a request.

Or as @nerdylist said you could use ajax to get your data back from server while displaying something to the user.

> Also, in case i have more users doinf the same thing (different jsons pages ofc) i wanted to know if it was in some way possible to create a queue of process.

You could do this, but I don't think it would be possible with php. However it seems quite difficult to me because you should do some inter-process communication.

The best answer would be to use threading+cache-system as the bottleneck here are the I/O for fetching the json files. Threads would allow you to load them simultaneously and not sequentially. But PHP is very bad at threading (no built-in support), however, there is a [library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) that do this, but I'm unsure you can use it if you cannot access the server.

Maybe you could move the code that consume the JSONs to the client side by porting it to javascript so you wouldn't waste server's badwidth with requests...

Anoter solution would be to delegate the requests for JSON to another process (write a script in another language that support threading and can load JSONs simultaneously) and call it through exec or some other subprocess-call-magic, then read the output of that process...

Comment: For the first part he could kick off the request with ajax on page load?

Comment: Right but as stated it could load while the user does there other things

Answer (score 0):

I can't expose the authentication key i use to retrieve the json, unfortunately..

You can check at this page => http://www.guyonwow.eu/grm/test.php
how slow it is just to fetch the json and print it on the screen.

Here is the super simple code of the above page:

```
<pre>
<?
$starttime = explode(' ', microtime());
$starttime = $starttime[1] + $starttime[0];
@$json = file_get_contents("https://json.url");
if($json == false) {
    die('Error!');
}   
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($decode);
$mtime = explode(' ', microtime());
$totaltime = $mtime[0] + $mtime[1] - $starttime;
printf('<center>Page loaded in %.3f seconds.</center><br />', $totaltime);
?>
</pre>
```

If i could at least start the request and let the user do other stuff, and once the fetching for all the json is done display a message in his notifications box that could also fix it.
The point is that i have no idea how can i let ajax handle it in background though. I think i can try something like this (seen in another post here)

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "import.php",
      data: { id: $('#json_id').val(), param_2: $('#param_2').val() }
    }).done(function() {
      alert('Done importing');
    });
});
```

Would that make it?